# Has SQRL been extensively audited?

Tags: sqrl

SQRL - [Secure, Quick, Reliable Login](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQRL) - is an open draft for user authentication.

Have there been "enough" publicly available tests to make any backed statements about the security of SQRL?

Comment: A quick google search doesn't show anything. I'm not sure anyone will spend time auditing a system which is not widely used or even known about.

Comment: @ztk I assumed so. This question is really just because someone claimed SQRL was "high security", with apparently no evidence to back that claim.

Comment: Many systems claim to be secure. Few are audited, and the audits generally have a limited scope

Comment: @ztk Exactly, hence my question if there are any statements at all backed by facts regarding the security of the scheme.